# replace words from text which matched with array value

Tags: php, arrays

My array $b is here:

```
rray(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "8989243three56"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "402three1345233"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "5023one345233"
}
```

Which I am getting at the end of my code in http://ideone.com/97HHmT

At last I want to check, if any value of `$b` is present in `$s` the main string or not. If present then it should be replace by `*`.

like input is `my long STRING with some Numbers 402three1345233 4023one345233` then result should be `my long STRING with some Numbers ************ *************` .

What change I should do in http://ideone.com/97HHmT?

Comment: Simply use `str_replace`

Comment: You have a typo with `my long STRING with some Numbers 402three1345233 4023one345233`. It should be `my long STRING with some Numbers 402three1345233 5023one345233`

Comment: Is there any reason why you replace your occurences by 12 `*` and 13 `*` ?

Comment: @Brewal: my program is to block numbers from text. SO i filtered such number and then replaced by `*`

Comment: I still cannot understand why there should be 12 times `*` instead of `402three1345233` i.e.

Comment: @Brewal: numers of start may be mistaken. but logic is replacing array value into text by `*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to replace occurences of `$b` values in your string with the exact same number of `*` than the `strlen` of the occurences :

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/XORzt5d0)**

```
$str = 'my long STRING with some Numbers 402three1345233 5023one345233';

foreach ($b as $occurence) {
    $str = str_replace($occurence, str_repeat('*', strlen($occurence)), $str);
}
```

See [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-repeat.php)

Comment: can you please tell why here actual number is not replace by same numbers of `*` http://ideone.com/97HHmT. check first number

Comment: You are mistaken. It's `$result = str_replace($occurence, str_repeat('*', strlen($occurence)), $result);` and you have to declare `$result = $s` before the loop. http://ideone.com/ymzLcd ... With your code, you replace occurences by the length of the **last** occurence, because `$b` is an array, and `str_replace` will loop each time through it

Comment: I updated, still does not seem to work. now it does not replace by *. Can you please see and update

Comment: See my link above, and check the dif... (I first made a mistake myself in my previous comment)

Answer (score 1):

try with `str_replace()`

```
$str = 'my long STRING with some Numbers 402three1345233 4023one345233';
echo str_replace($b, '**********', $str);
// output :- my long STRING with some Numbers ********** **********
```

Comment: it gives `my long STRING with 124 mynumberis * some Numbers * *` can you please check ideone?

Comment: replace value set in array will be replace or give me your string and array

Comment: @Rakhesh: dude, I want to replace exactly array values into `$str`. not putting `*`statically

Comment: i have puted $b is an array if $b array values found in $str then will replaceswith ******

Comment: thanks rakesh. Did you added link? code is also not seems edited

Comment: change $str to your input variable

Comment: I did it, but please see another answer. What I wanted is there. But thanks a  lot for you help

Comment: your welcome :) you need to mention in answer about stars you want